# KIE Workbench when the jar is integrated with Spring Boot APP

Tags: java, spring, jbpm, kie, kie-workbench

I am planning to build a KIE jar which includes all my process definitions. I am planning on integrating this with my Spring Boot application. The Spring Boot application will have UI built using Angular JS. If I am embed the KIE jar within a webapplication , would it also give me access to KIE workbench under a different context path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming "build a KIE jar which includes all my process definitions" means only your rules/processes with the Drools runtime dependencies, then no.  You would have to include the additional KIE dependencies for the WorkBench et al to embed it in your own app.  If doing so, it is better to do so as a separate module/app as the KIE WorkBench is a rules and process authoring environment, not a runtime environment.

Comment: Thanks @Jeff. I am not using drools but rather BPMN processes. I believe the KIE jar has both runtime and the process definition.

Comment: Yes it does - definitions.  "would it also give me access to KIE workbench under a different context path?" - KWB is an authoring app, and not included in a KIE jar.

Comment: Thanks again. So should it be deployed as a separate app in the server ? Also how can it be linked to different kie instances for reporting ?

Comment: Yes, deploy as a separate app(s) in same or different server.  The manuals list properties for configuring communication between KWB, KS, etc.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, it is very useful.